# client not connecting to node js server on AWS with WSS/WS protocols

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io

I created a small server using socket.io and node js and deployed in heroku earlier. I was easily able to have client connected to server with wss/ws protocol but when I deployed my app too AWS, Clients are not connecting. I debugged the application in client side but Its just not connecting to server. Did I miss something? are there extra steps needs to followed to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: application LB does not support WS protocol. you can use socket.io. here https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp is based on socket.io and will work fine over http and https behinde load balancer, just enable sticky session. you can NLB for WS.

Comment: ALB supports ws and if https listener is present, it can support wss as well but it seems you're not using ALB but connecting directly to instance running ws, check if the server is listening on the port you have mentioned for ws.

Comment: @JamesDean you are right. I had to add Load Balancer and had to .ebextensions folder with some config file in my project. Also added TCP listener. I got it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I had to add .ebextensions folder with a config in my project root directory. You can look at the following tutorial to make it work https://nikhilmopidevi.github.io/2017/10/18/WebSockets-with-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk/